# Rails 3: displaying error full messages in flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, custom-validators

Here is my CreditCard model:

```
validate :name_is_split_properly
  private
    def name_is_split_properly
      if last_name.blank?
        self.errors[:base] << "Last Name is required"
      end
    end
```

When a user submits a CreditCard, the validation takes place and this is how I am setting the error(s) in a flash message:

```
flash[:error] = current_order.errors.full_messages.join('\n')
redirect_to new_order_path(:client_id => params[:client_id])
```

But for some reason when the `flash[error]` is displayed in the view, this is how its displayed: `Credit card base Last Name is required`... how do I get rid of the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `errors.add(:base, "Last Name is required")`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before and it didn't work.. I forgot to mention that when a user is entering in their CreditCard its actually inside of a nested form for the `Order`... so the full_message is displaying the Model name of where the error came from... does that make sense?